# Singly linked list in pure C - follow-up

Tags: c, linked-list, memory-management

This is an update for [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117415/singly-linked-list-in-pure-c) post.

I fixed all style-issues from the comments, but still have a few questions left:

- Someone commented that my last post contained too many functions, which could be easily implemented by the user of the *library* himself. Is this a basic enough set of functions? Is anything missing? (I hid the `SLNode struct` on purpose, since the user doesn't have to know how this list is implemented).
- The user currently doesn't free elements by himself (since the `SLNode struct` isn't exposed - he should use `SLList_remove`. Thus if he adds the same data to the list twice (without an extra `malloc` call) and removes one of the two nodes from the list, the data is freed and the left node points to data, which is not there. How should I manage this? Should I expose the `SLNode`?
- The library handles wrong input (`NULL` as list or invalid list index) by returning failure codes (`-1`). Or is *undefined behavior* more C-Stylish? - The user has to check for valid input and it's not my job.

**Updated SLList.h**

```
#ifndef SINGLYLINKEDLIST_
#define SINGLYLINKEDLIST_

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct SLList SLList;

// Create SinglyLinkedList
SLList *SLList_create(void);

// Get information about SinglyLinkedList
size_t SLList_length(SLList *list);

// Get data from SinglyLinkedList element
void  *SLList_get(SLList *list, size_t index);

// Insert/remove elements from SinglyLinkedList
int SLList_insert(SLList *list, void *data, size_t index);
int SLList_remove(SLList *list, size_t index);

// Clear/free SinglyLinkedList
void SLList_clear(SLList *list);
void SLList_free(SLList *list);

#endif  /* ifdef SINGLYLINKEDLIST_ */
```

**Updated SLList.c**

```
#include "SLList.h"

/***************************
 *   UNEXPOSED FUNCTIONS   *
 ***************************/
typedef struct SLNode SLNode;

struct SLList {
  SLNode *head;
  size_t length;  
};

struct SLNode {
  SLNode *next;
  void *data;
};

SLNode *SLNode_create(void *data);
void SLNode_free(SLNode *node);

SLNode *SLNode_create(void *data) {
  SLNode *node = calloc(sizeof(SLNode), 1);
  if (node != NULL) node->data = data;
  return node;
}

void SLNode_free(SLNode *node) {
  if (node == NULL) return;
  free(node->data);
  free(node);
}

/***************************
 *    EXPOSED FUNCTIONS    *
 ***************************/

/**
 * createSLList: Creates an SLList with default-
 *               values (head: 0x0, length: 0).
 *
 * @return Pointer to createsSLList.
 *         NULL on allocation failure.
 */
SLList *SLList_create(void) {
  return calloc(sizeof(SLList), 1);
}

/**
 * SLList_length: Returns current number of nodes in
 *                SLList.
 * 
 * @param list SLList to return length from.
 *
 * @return Number of nodes in SLList.
 */
size_t SLList_length(SLList *list) {
  if (list == NULL) return 0;
  else              return list->length;
}

/**
 * SLList_get: Get data from list element
 *             at specific index.
 *
 * @param list  SLList to search in.
 * @param index Index of element to look for.
 *
 * @return Element-data on success.
 *         NULL on invalid arguments.
 */
void *SLList_get(SLList *list, size_t index) {
  if (list == NULL)          return NULL;
  if (list->length <= index) return NULL;

  size_t i;
  SLNode *node = list->head;
  for (i = 0; i < index; i++) { node = node->next; }

  return node->data;
}

/**
 * slAdd: Add data to SLList.
 *
 * @param list  SLList to add data to.
 * @param data  Pointer to data, which should
 *              be added to SLList (should be
 *              allocated with malloc/calloc/etc.).
 * @param index Position in LList to add data
 *              (Range between 0 and list->length).
 *
 * @return 0  on success.
 *         -1 on failure (invalid input, allocation failure).
 */
int SLList_insert(SLList *list, void *data, size_t index) {
  if (list == NULL)               return -1;
  else if (list->length < index)  return -1;

  SLNode *node = SLNode_create(data); 
  if (node == NULL) return -1;

  if (index == 0) {
    node->next = list->head;
    list->head = node;
  } else {
    SLNode *prev = list->head;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 1; i < index; i++) { prev = prev->next; };
    node->next = prev->next;
    prev->next = node;
  }

  list->length++;
  return 0;
}
/**
 * slRemove: Remove data from SLList.
 *
 * @param list  SLList to remove from.
 * @param index Index of element to remove
 *              (Range between 0 and list->length-1);
 *
 * @return 0  on success.
 *         -1 on failure (invalid input).
 */
int SLList_remove(SLList *list, size_t index) {
  if (list == NULL)          return -1;
  if (list->length <= index) return -1;

  SLNode *node;
  if (index == 0) {
    node = list->head;
    list->head = node->next;
  } else {
    size_t i;
    SLNode *prev = list->head;
    for (i = 1; i < index; i++) {prev = prev->next; };
    node = prev->next;
    prev->next = node->next;
  }

  SLNode_free(node);
  list->length--;
  return 0;
}

void SLList_clear(SLList *list) {
  if (list == NULL) return;

  SLNode *node, *tmp;
  node = list->head;

  while (node != NULL) {
    tmp = node->next; 
    SLNode_free(node);
    node = tmp;
  }

  list->head   = NULL;
  list->length = 0;
}

void SLList_free(SLList *list) {
  SLList_clear(list);
  free(list);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How does your user iterate the list?

Currently looping over the items in your list takes O(N<sup>2</sup>), since randomly accessing a single element via `SLList_get()` takes O(N). Linked lists iteration via jumping to each next element will allow looping in O(N).

I'd add to `SLList.h`:

```
typedef struct SLNode SLNode;

// Fetch a list node
SLNode* SLList_node(SLList *list, size_t index);
// For a given node, return the next or NULL if end of list
SLNode* SLList_next(SLNode *node);
// For a given node, return the data it stores
void* SLList_data(SLNode *node);
```

And to `SLList.c`:

```
SLNode* SLList_node(SLList *list, size_t index)
{
  size_t i;
  SLNode *node = list->head;
  for (i = 0; i < index && node; i++) { node = node->next; }
  return node;
}

SLNode* SLList_next(SLNode *node)
{
  return node->next;
}

void* SLList_data(SLNode *node)
{
  return node->data;
}

// SLList_get can be simplified now:
void  *SLList_get(SLList *list, size_t index) {
  SLNode *node = SLList_node(list, index);
  return node->data;
}
```

Now your user can iterate very easily with:

```
SLNode *n;
for(n = SLList_node(list, 0); n; n = SLList_next(n)) {
  void *data = SLList_data(n);
  // do something with data
}
```

### Don't play nice with bad inputs

I'm not sure what the point of `SLList_remove()` returning -1 is. The user has to test the return value. They could have just ensured/tested that `list != NULL && index < SLList_length(list)`. You are not removing any burden from the user and the return can be better used (see next section).

The only exception I'd make to this is the `SLList_node()` function I added, which checks if an index is out of bounds of the list and returns `NULL`.  This is required so the user knows when they've iterated to the end of the list.

### Don't free the user's data

Safely freeing and cleaning up the data stored in the list may be more complex than calling `free(node->data)`. `node->data` could be a `FILE*` that needs closing or a complex data structure that contains memory to be freed. It could have been allocated with a non-standard allocator. Instead I'd have `SLList_remove()` return the data that was in the node for the user to clean up themselves:

```
void* SLList_remove(SLList *list, size_t index);
```

Example usage:

```
void *data = SLList_remove(list, idx);
free(data);
```

### Example user code to free the list

Since the user must be responsible for destroying the data that they created, I would remove `SLList_clear()`. So `SLNode_free()` becomes:

```
void SLNode_free(SLNode *node) {
  free(node);
}
```

User code to clear and free the list them becomes:

```
void *data;
while(data = SLNode_remove(list, 0)) { /* clean up data e.g. free(data); */ }
SLList_free(list);
```

### Add a fast insertion function

I'd recommend implementing a fast insert function to insert a node after an existing node in O(1) instead of having to use `SLList_insert()` which is O(N).

```
// Insert data after an existing node
SLNode* SLList_add_after(SLList *list, SLNode *after, void *data) {
  SLNode *node = SLNode_create(data);
  if(!node) return NULL;
  node->next = after->next;
  after->next = node;
  list->length++;
  return node;
}
```

**Edit:** Added example user code to clear the list

Comment: Wow, thank you really much! I didn't think about the *O(n^2)* iteration over the list. First I was a little skeptical to expose `SLNode`, but it makes sense and the *O(1)* insert is a great idea. Also the handling of the data is simple and appropriate. I'll need to let go of the input-validation, which is somehow hard for me, but it seems more C-like and if I think about it, it would be awful if this was always the case (error checking on math-operators and every single `std`-function). The user has to care for himself.

Comment: How should I handle `SLList_clear` without freeing the data? Should I return nothing or should I create an array of `void **` and return it?

Comment: I have the same thoughts about `SLList_free`. Should it free the data or not?

Comment: I'ved added example user code to free the list, without using `SLList_clear()` and updated `SLList_free()`. You could also add a helper function that free'd all nodes and the list but didn't free the `SLNode->data` pointers.